# Windows XP Pro fails to install even though Windows 7 works

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, installation, windows-installer

I had a Windows XP Professional installation running fine until suddenly it stopped working and showed following error while booting:

```
NTOSKRNL.EXE is missing or corrupt.
```

I tried to boot through different bootable CDs (Windows XP Professional) but they all froze soon after the "press any key to boot from CD......" message. Windows 7 installed successfully, but I need to install Windows XP Professional as my system configuration isn't suitable for Windows 7.

Please suggest a solution to get Windows XP installed and running again.

Comment: Could be a problem with your Windows XP Pro install disk? Have you attempted to use a different installation disk?

Comment: Do you have multiple partitions?

Comment: @Thiago M.: Yes i have tried different installation disks too.

Comment: @Kyle: Yes i have multiple partitions.

Comment: Hmm it's been a while since I have encountered this error... I remember having to delete the partition and recreate it.

Comment: OKay so a quick search refreshed my memory, if the disk is fine and windows 7 installs fine it may be a problem with your partition table. Try deleting the partition and remaking it I don't remember having to delete other partitions but if it continues to fail it might be worth a shot.

Comment: In addition to what Kyle said; you can use the Windows 7 install disk to delete the partitions and recreate them and then try booting from the XP install disk.

Comment: That particular file was is from the NT days I don't think windows 7 includes it any more, it holds alot of important information that the kernel needs to operate. It also one of the first files loaded during boot and installations.

Comment: @Thiago M: I can't afford  deleting and recreating partitions because my data is too important to me.

Comment: Have you installed windows 7 first and now trying to make a dual boot? IF not then is first setup of windows Xp runs I mean to say that the console part of windows or not?

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge and experience, I would suggest that you should try to use the another hard disk (no specification space is mandatory) and than format it. Your problem will be solved.

I was having the same problem and I changed my hard disk and now I am using Windows XP on the new hard disk and on the old hard disk O have installed.